# How to remove real-time firebase listener in Python

Tags: python, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a firebase real-time listener like so:

```
db.reference('/tasks').child(user_id).listen(handle_task)
```

Now, I want to remove that listener (turning it off), In other words, stop getting events for this reference, but I can't find out how to do that in Python.

Heres an example of how to remove event listener in Java:

```
databaseReference.removeEventListener(valueEventListener);
```

Answer (score 1):

**Cloud Firestore:**
From the official documentation:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen#detach_a_listener

```
doc_watch.unsubscribe()
```

**Firebase Realtime Database**
From the official documentation:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/python/firebase_admin.db#listenerregistration

```
.close()
```

Comment: Thanks but it is for Cloud Firestore, I need it for Realtime Database, but I found a solution already, you just need to store the listener in variable then just do .close()

Comment: Sorry my bad. Yes also this is found in the documentation here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/python/firebase_admin.db#listenerregistration

Answer (score 0):

The following worked for me:

```
listener_registration = firebase_admin.db.reference(path).listen(listenerObject.listener)
listener_registration.close()
```